# Display plain text(not rendering html syntax) in laravel

Tags: html, laravel

Currently I use database to store all data(description, name, etc) that user key in (user can self generate content)

Yet, my site is "hijacked" by someone who knows html..
Let's say in description, they enter

```
<a href="http://hijack.comhijack">abc</a>
```

to put link:

[image: Link]

The code in my Larvel view is `{{$site->description}}`

How can I restrict them to show this like plain text?
[image]

Tt will mess-up my page, and when I put my description in meta property, it will mess up to..

any solution for this?

Comment: You have to HTML escape the data. If you're using blade, use triple curly braces: `{{{ $site->description }}}`

Comment: Are you are talking about escping `HTML` from user input ?

Comment: @WesleyMurch thanks, how bout i want break line to remain(not escaping)

Comment: @WereWolf-TheAlpha ya. escaping, i doesn't know how to say it. sorry.

Comment: If you are saving the user submitted data in to database then Validation of that field will protect you and inputs are sanitized (AFAIK).

Comment: @WereWolf-TheAlpha No, *always* sanitize output, context sensitive. You can do this in addition to input validation but it is possible a page title might include HTML that should be escaped, for example a title like "`My opinion on <table> VS. <div>`"

Comment: Yes, depending on context. If I allow `HTML` then I should do that definitely @WesleyMurch

Answer (score 4):

In Laravel 5, double curly braces now automatically escape all the HTML from your string.

More info: [Blade templating](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/blade)

---

If you're still using Laravel 4, use triple curly braces instead of double, which will escape all the HTML from your string:

```
{{{ $site->description }}}
```

Answer (score 1):

No need to use any blade syntax for this just use normal PHP:

```
<?php echo $site->description; ?>
```

I am new to Laravel and was looking for a blade solution but this worked for me and seemed to be the simplest solution

Answer (score -2):

you can try :

```
{!! $site->description !!}
```